# how to use arrow keys as an input in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-7, arrow-keys

I was curious if there was a way to use the arrow keys on your keyboard to be able to receive input form them and use this information in a batch file?  Thanks
BurnE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a few ways that you can assign arrows symbols/keys to variable, but u can't use them as input as they are operational buttons in command prompt (move cursor and iterate trough the already executed commands) and you cant's detect their pressing.

**EDIT:**

```
@echo off
CHCP 1251

::Define a Linefeed variable
set LF=^


::above 2 blank lines are critical - do not remove
endlocal

call :hexPrint "0x1a" upArrow
call :hexPrint "0x1b" downArrow
call :hexPrint "0x18" rightArrow
call :hexPrint "0x19" leftArrow

echo %upArrow%  %downArrow% %rightArrow% %leftArrow% 

goto :eof
:hexPrint  string  [rtnVar]
  for /f eol^=^%LF%%LF%^ delims^= %%A in (
    'forfiles /p "%~dp0." /m "%~nx0" /c "cmd /c echo(%~1"'
  ) do if "%~2" neq "" (set %~2=%%A) else echo(%%A
exit /b
```

this will set the arrows to a variables , but result might depends on your `CHCP`.I've used [this as reference](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3857) .Will not work on XP if have no `forfiles`

Comment: Could you tell me how to do this?